# Does the NPC wizard 'Diviner' regain their Portent ability on use of a scroll?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Most NPCs use a flat-basic stat block in lieu of character classes. Please observe the [Diviner](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/diviner), a 15th level caster, from *Volo's Guide to Monsters*. This Diviner wizard has (1) class feature, the daily use of *one* 'Portent' ability (similar to the Wizard class ability):

> **Portent** (*Recharges after the Diviner Casts a Divination Spell of 1st Level or Higher*). When the diviner or a creature it can see makes an attack roll, a saving throw, or an ability check, the diviner can roll a d20 and choose to use this roll in place of the attack roll, saving throw, or ability check.

In contrast with the [Divination Wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#SchoolofDivination) sub-class, NPC wizards can 'recharge' this Portent-ability after the use of any spell from the Divination spell-list.

*Explanation on relevance:* PCs tend to lack [Legendary Resistances](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77911/do-creatures-with-legendary-resistance-know-what-theyre-making-a-saving-throw-a) and equivalents. Such a Diviner could modify any [save or suck spell or situation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96749/my-dm-insists-on-rolling-a-single-save-for-groups-affected-by-aoe-save-spells-h). Say this wizard observes a PC group against a [Beholder](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/beholder), [Medusa](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/medusa) or [Dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/ancient-red-dragon), they need only cast a single [divination spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/school/divination) to change dice rolls accordingly. Less need for a [Long Rest](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring). Logically, these wizards (of 18+ intelligence) would want as many (cheap) divination spell slots as possible.

Thus, such a wizard would seek to restore spell slots via things like a  [Pearl of Power](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140899/does-a-pearl-of-power-create-new-slots). As the magic item list in 5e is extensive, let us focus on [spell scrolls](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/spell-scroll). These magic items are relatively easy to make (1st level spell-scrolls are 'common' magic items) and seem to approximate a wizard casting their own spell.

- If it is relevant, the answer below can include spell scrolls made specifically by this Diviner-wizard themselves &/or those made by other caster-enchanter-scribes. Does it make a difference if they are casting their 'own' spell or not?
- If possible, I would be thankful if the answer could also include the infamous [Rings or Ioun Stones of Spell Storing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing). Does it make a difference if the wizard is regaining their 'own' spell via some external source?

---

**Question Specific & Detailed:** Can the NPC 'Divination' wizard (from *Volo's Guide*) restore their daily *Portent* ability by casting a divination-type spell from a spell scroll magical item - or can this Portent-reuse only be gained via memory-slot spell casting?

Comment: There is a chance this isn't a duplicate. Are you asking about the Refresh or asking about PCs having access to this NPC?

Comment: I'm confused as to how this is a duplicate. It's not asking about applying Portent but recharging it. If we have a question like "Does using a spell scroll count as casting a spell" it would be a dupe to me. Oh but the class features the dupe asks about applying all require casting spells... I see how this is a dupe then; [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/50065) seems especially relevant

Comment: @Medix2 Yeah, there's a few questions in here. I'm not sure which one they're actually asking. Although the final question specific seems to be asking about does the Portent use recharge from a spell scroll casting. Whether or not it's PC rules vs NPC rules is a difference maker is I guess the focus.

Comment: "Does this NPC's 'Portent' reboot-restore from a (divination spell) scroll use?" Not a 'dupe', but i am sure it is related to many other posts. Not asking about PCs with access to this NPC - that is an example only.

Comment: This is a specific version of the general question in the duplicate target, and it doesn't appear to have any specifics that would preclude the answers to the general question. Is there something we've missed about this question that renders those answers inapplicable to this situation?